# MATLAB: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error even though I'm not indexing anything

Tags: matlab

I have the following simple function, but when I call it with the argument `'single'`, I get an "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error. The thing that confuses me is: I'm not indexing anything in this code, so what is MATLAB talking about?

```
function meps = meps(prec)
%Computes the machine precision for 32-bit or 64-bit floats.

if nargin == 0
    precision = 'double';
else
    precision = prec;
end

if precision == 'single'
    meps = single(1.0);
else
    meps = 1.0;
end

while (1 + meps) > 1

    meps = meps / 2;

end
```

executing

```
meps('single')
```

causes the error, while executing just

```
meps()
```

without passing an argument works as expected.

Comment: Works fine for me. Try restarting MATLAB.

Comment: Perhaps either `single` (as seen in `single(1.0)`) or `while` (as seen in `while(1+meps)` has been redefined as a matrix.  Check your workspace for suspicious variables

Comment: Thanks @excaza, indeed, after I restarted MATLAB, it worked. Very weird. I guess I'll delete this question.

Comment: @Alex it's most likely because you had a lingering variable called `single`, as @BenVoigt points out

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` . Use `strcmp`. You could also just use `meps = ones(prec);` and avoid the two `if` statements (though you still might want to do some input validation). Also it's generally bad to use a variable with the same name as your function.

Comment: @horchler good points, I'll change those things. Thanks for your feedback, and for everybody else's!